# How to calculate the sum of a column from set of rows based on a condition in gridview?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Visit https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwGF3.png

I am new to VB.NET and I want to find the sum of Quantity where BatchIDs are Equal. In this example, answer should be 'PAN-NEW'= 4,VSD-1850=2
My aim is to check the result with Current Stock before invoicing.
How to do this in vb.net? Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the DataGridView and check if the row satisfies your condition then add.

```
For each row as DataGridViewRow in DataGridView1.Rows
   If row.Cells(2).Value = "PAN-NEW" Then
      quantitySum = quantitySum + Integer.Parse(row.Cells(4).Value)
   End if
Next
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am confused..how can I find the sum(qty) of all BatchID , it should be group wise(BatchID)

Comment: I could solve this by using nested loop, Thanks  for the idea.